# django passing ajax response to php variable

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am using ajax to send a request to my django function which then generates a zip file and serves it to the user. If i go to the url `domain.com/django/builder/zipit/` the fileis generated as expected and downloaded to my computer, but when using ajax and the response is returned, ajax cant download it. Can I pass the response to a php variable and download it that way? Using a iframe wont work because the file is created dynamically.

ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/django/builder/zipit/',
    data: serialize,
    success: function(response){
        //pass response to php somehow
    }
```

views.py

```
def send_zipfile(request):
temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
archive = zipfile.ZipFile(temp, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
filename = '/home/dbs/public_html/download/video.html'
archive.write(filename, 'file.html')
archive.close()
wrapper = FileWrapper(temp)
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/zip', mimetype='application/x-download')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=dbs_content.zip'
response['Content-Length'] = temp.tell()
temp.seek(0)
return response
```

Comment: What does PHP have to do with it?

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/610641-file-download-ajax

Comment: what is your response content ??

Comment: @Priyank Patel the response content is the .zip file that should automatically start downloading.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman because php can save content directly to your computer, javascript cant.

Comment: @user1442957 that's complete nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to pass it to PHP variable.Everything is possible in django itself.

mimetype set to application/x-zip-compressed

But beware, creating zip archives on each request is bad idea and this may kill your server (not counting timeouts if the archives are large). Performance-wise approach is to cache generated output somewhere in filesystem and regenerate it only if source files have changed. Even better idea is to prepare archives in advance (eg. by cron job) and have your web server serving them as usual statics.

```
# archive_list = ["ZipTest1.txt", "ZipTest2.txt", "ZipTest3.txt"]
# # save the files in the archive_list into a PKZIP format .zip file
# zfilename = "Wife101.zip"
# zout = zipfile.ZipFile(zfilename, "w")
# for fname in archive_list:
# zout.write(fname)
# zout.close()
return HttpResponse(zout,mimetupe="application/x-zip-compressed")
```

Comment: I added my views.py to my post

Comment: Try the above mentioned mimetype

Comment: I did and i works if I visit the link directly, but if i call it from ajax, it wont download